# Find out where a commit is a in a git merge tree?

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm trying to a `git bisect` of a range of git commits that contain merges.

I've done `git log A..B` to find commits that might be the problem.

I would quite like to know how the commits relate to  one another and I would prefer to not spend an awful lot of time scrolling in `gitk`.

A neat trick in maths is representing a "path" through a binary tree as a sequence of bits. So e.g.
So: 1101 could mean (right branch of first merge,right branch of second merge, left branch of third merge, right branch of  fourth merge).

It would be cool if I could attach a sequence like this to every git commit. How might I do this?

## Updates in response to question

As knittl points out below, Git trees can contain merges with more than two children - so one might need to extend the "bit sequence" to include numbers greater than 1. Like 010134

As pointed out by Romain, the relative rev specs HEAD^1^2^3 is effectively the same as this sequence.

I am not fully convinced by the value of these bit sequences yet, and likely have to use them a bit first. But they have a few child properties.

- If two commits have the same bit sequences then there are no merges between them
- If a commits bit sequence is a prefix of another's then you know that the commit with the  shorter sequence has had the other commit merged into it.

The "git commit tree" is a actually dag. So in theory there can be more than path to a commit (the root of the git tree being an obvious examle) and then it has two sequences of bits associated with it - which could be a little confusing.

Comment: Have you considered the `<ref>~n / <ref>^n` relative notation? (detailed doc with examples on [this page](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions), just above "SPECIFYING RANGES"). You might want to script something to programmatically walk the commits tree by constructing refs. For a very simple example, your "right-right-left-right from HEAD would be `HEAD^2^2^1^2` IF merges are consecutive.

Comment: That notation looks interesting. Are there any trees that will output convert sha git commits into this relative notation?

Comment: @RomainValeri I agree that this format in the same as the binary format I was specifying, not much more verbose and more standard.

Comment: Note that the Git DAG is _not_ a binary tree, it's a graph. A merge commit can have 3 or more parents and each commit can have arbitrarily many child commits. And how does `1101` help you visualize the relationship better than a visual representation with gitk? (I'm genuinely curious)

Comment: @knittl Yeah, that is a good point and I was thinking about it. In practice in my tree all the merges will have two parents but a format like `0121` works as too, though  I think I've decided this "HEAD^0^1^2^1" path is the way to go. On the utility of this string: if two commits have the same bits there are no merges between them, if a commit's bit is a prefix of another's then you know that the commit with the longer sequence has been merged.

Comment: I don't really see why you care if two commits have a merge between them. If bisect shows that the merge introduced a bug, you've still found what you wanted.

Comment: @useless All good if a bisect does what it's meant to do - when you start getting commits then move in and out working and breaking and want to know what is going on it starts becoming a bit more annoying.

Comment: But you expect a binary search to switch between good and bad commits. Do you mean it never gets to a result, or you don't understand the result, or what?

Comment: It tells me a commit is "bad" when this commit actually passes - so I sort of want to work out what's going on in the tree.